# How to list a directory with expect via sftp connection

Tags: linux, shell, sftp, expect

I have this expect script but the list of files does not present me correctly.

expect.dat

```
set timeout 10000
spawn sftp -o ConnectTimeout=3 user@192.1.6.6
expect "*?assword*"
send   "tech\r"
expect "sftp>"
send   "cd /global/scripts/log\r"
expect "sftp>"
send   "ls 20220703*\r"
expect "sftp>"
send   "bye\r"
```

Expect command

```
expect expect.dat
```

Result

```
spawn sftp -o ConnectTimeout=3 user@192.1.6.6
Password:
Connected to user@192.1.6.6.
sftp> cd /global/scripts/log
sftp> ls 20220703*
20220703_A.log        20220703_A.xls
20220703_E.log        20220703_E_r.log
sftp> You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/dm
```

how to get this result?

```
20220703_A.log
20220703_A.xls
20220703_E.log
20220703_E_r.log
```

Comment: Expect uses [tag:tcl] which is also a general-purpose programming language. you can use Tcl's builtin [commands](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.html) to manipulate the data the way you like.

Comment: you can also use shell (or any other tools) to process the output from `expect expect.dat`.

Answer (score 1):

First, use the sftp command `ls -1 20220703*` to produce output in a single column.

Next, use `log_user 0` and `spawn -noecho sftp ...` to hide all the excess output.

Last, and the trickiest part, capture the `ls` output so that can be printed out cleanly: we have to handle the fact that the command we just "typed" will be given back to us.

```
set ls_cmd "ls -1 20220703*"
send   "$ls_cmd\r"

# capture the command's output
expect -re "$ls_cmd\r\n(.*)\r\nsftp>"
puts $expect_out(1,string)

send   "bye\r"
expect eof     # wait for sftp to exit cleanly
```

expect gives you the process's output using `\r\n` line endings.